# NgIf block in Angular breaks Http Call

Tags: angular, angular5

Without the ngIf block the http call works fine and the table is getting populated without any issues but with the ngIf block, i m getting the error as

```
<div *ngIf="isloading; else other_content">
      <ng-template #content>
        <mat-progress-spinner [color]="color"
                              [mode]="mode"
                              [value]="value">
        </mat-progress-spinner>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
    <ng-template #other_content>
      <uitk-dynamic-table id="incidentTable" #dt [model]="incidents" [modelObservable]="incidentObservable">
        <uitk-column-def [id]="incidents.columns[0].id">
          <ng-template #cellTemplate let-col="column" let-record="record">
            <span>{{record[col.id]}}</span>
          </ng-template>
        </uitk-column-def>
      </uitk-dynamic-table>
      <h2>Tasks</h2>
      <uitk-dynamic-table id="taskTable" #dt [model]="tasks" [modelObservable]="taskObservable">
        <uitk-column-def [id]="tasks.columns[0].id">
          <ng-template #cellTemplate let-col="column" let-record="record">
            <span>{{record[col.id]}}</span>
          </ng-template>
        </uitk-column-def>
      </uitk-dynamic-table>
    </ng-template>
```

This is the component code

```
    private incidentObservable: Observable<any>;
  private incidentObserver: Observer<any>;
  private taskObservable: Observable<any>;
  private taskObserver: Observer<any>;
  private employeeID: string;
  private msID: string;
  private incidentAPI: string;
  private incidentID: string;
  private taskAPI: string;
  private id: string;
  private isloading: boolean;

  color = 'primary';
  mode = 'indeterminate';
  value = 50;

  incidents = {
    title: 'Incidents',
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: false,
    clearAllFilters: false,
    caseSensitiveFilter: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    filterCondition: {
      columnSorting: {
        columnId: 'IncidentId',
        sortOrder: 1
      }
    },
    columns: [
      { label: 'Incident', id: 'IncidentId', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Description', id: 'ShortDescription', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Assignment', id: 'Assignment', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'State', id: 'State', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'UksProduct', id: 'UksProduct', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Owner', id: 'WorkgroupOwner', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Opened', id: 'DateOpened', dataType: 'date' },
      { label: 'SLA', id: 'SlaIndicator', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Caller', id: 'SlaIndicator', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Closed', id: 'SlaIndicator', dataType: 'date' }
    ],
    records: []
  };


  tasks = {
    title: 'Tasks',
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: false,
    clearAllFilters: false,
    caseSensitiveFilter: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    filterCondition: {
      columnSorting: {
        columnId: 'TaskId',
        sortOrder: 1
      }
    },
    columns: [
      { label: 'Task', id: 'TaskId', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Description', id: 'ShortDescription', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Assignment', id: 'Assignment', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'State', id: 'State', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Opened', id: 'CreateDate', dataType: 'date' },
      { label: 'Caller', id: 'SlaIndicator', dataType: 'text' },
      { label: 'Closed', id: 'SlaIndicator', dataType: 'date' }
    ],
    records: []
  };

  tempModel = {
    subText: "The application will be available shortly."
    //imageUrl: "../../loading.png" // Test to display under the Page Loader
  };

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private _cardService: DashboardCardService, private plis: PageLoadingIndicatorService) {
    this.incidentObservable = new Observable(obj => this.incidentObserver = obj);
    this.taskObservable = new Observable(obj => this.taskObserver = obj);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.plis.showLoader();
    this.isloading = true;

    this._cardService.InputData.subscribe(data => {
      this.employeeID = data.EmployeeId;
      this.msID = data.MSId;
      this.incidentID = data.MSId;
    });
    // if employeeID is null, then msid would be used to fetch the data. employeeID is given preference over msid as it will be more accurate. If required, we can change the order later
    this.id = this.employeeID || this.msID || this.incidentID;

    this.getIncidentData().subscribe((incidentResponse) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isloading = false;
        console.log(incidentResponse);
        this.incidents.records = incidentResponse.Incidents.slice(0, 5);
        this.incidentObserver.next(this.incidents);

      }, 8000);

    });

    this.getTaskData().subscribe((taskResponse) => {
      console.log(taskResponse);
      this.tasks.records = taskResponse.Tasks.slice(0, 5);
      this.taskObserver.next(this.tasks);

    });
  }

  getIncidentData(): Observable<any> {
    //If you are running just the angular App alone instead of running the entire application, uncomment the below line and comment the service call
    //return this._http.get('incident.json');
    this.incidentAPI = AppConstants.incidentAPI + this.id;
    return this._cardService.getIncidentData(this.incidentAPI);
  }

  getTaskData(): Observable<any> {
    //If you are running just the angular App alone instead of running the entire application, uncomment the below line and comment the service call
    // return this._http.get('task.json');
    this.taskAPI = AppConstants.taskAPI + this.id;
    return this._cardService.getTaskData(this.taskAPI);
  }
```

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (service-now.component.ts:124)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at*

Comment: Please give more context in the code. Where is `this.getTaskData()` called?

Comment: it is called in the corresponding component file.. and as i mentioned if i dont use if else block and merely use the table directive, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize every variable in .ts file which is being populated dynamically.

In your code you are directly trying to assign value to undefined variable.So make sure you define or assign some value  to this.

`taskObserver = new Subject<any>(); //import { Subject } from 'rxjs';`

[here you go...good ref site for explanantion](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: I havent pasted the entire component code but the declaration has been taken care. and as i said, it works without the ngif block

Comment: I dont know the root cause. but if i do visibility hidden for the table  <div [ngStyle]="{'visibility' : !isloading ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"> instead of doing it as < div *ngIf> it works.. don know what is the case

Comment: can you try `[ngIf]="isloading" [ngIfElse]="otherContent"` putting this condition in `<ng-template #content>` this block.remove outer `<div>` block.And make sure to use camel casing instead `_`(undescore)

Comment: Thanks. I wil try this way and update you. Meanwhile i have a question from the link you have shared for  BehaviourSubject. I posted it in stackoverflow before as well. For sharing data between components, a normal service with a private scope variable is fine. Right.. Why we need to go for BehaviourSubject specifically?

Comment: @NewBee, as per my understandin, A BehaviorSubject holds one value. when it is subscribed it emits the value immediately. A Subject doesn't hold a value. let's say you have created one object with `Subject` then you are calling `.next(1)` on to this, then in your output will be empty, but if you are doing same thing with BehaviourSubject, you will get output as 1.

Comment: No.. What i m saying is.. Before angular, we create a service and we will have private scope variable. We will store the value in the private scope variable.. like var myStorageValue="store my value" and in the controller or any other logical component, we will call like myService.myStorageValue.. This is what we have done till angular. But whats the use case that supports the use of BehaviourSubject or Subject... If you think of it, u ll get to know all situations will not demand implementing it in observable pattern.

Comment: @NewBee, in angular 1.x, we used this approach, but if we refresh the page after fetching data from service, that data will be vanished & we can't create custom observables in that, also with promise we can get data for one time, but in the advanced version you can create your own observables.Observable is preferred over Promise because it provides the features of Promise and more.With Observable it doesn't matter if you want to handle 0, 1, or multiple events.It will keep giving you data as soon as it fetches new data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not initialize your variable `taskObserver`

Make sure you have initialized as -

```
taskObserver = new Subject<any>();
```

Comment: I declared it and just for sake of the post, i shared half of the code. And as i mentioned in my post, the code works , if i remove the ngif template in the html and include table directive alone

Comment: Can you print the log for `this.incidentObserver` before it calls `next` function.

Comment: i did debugging and when it reaches this.incidentObserver it comes as undefined. And as you have seen, i delcared it at the top and also if i remove my ngIF template and debug the code it works fine

Comment: I dont know the root cause. but if i do visibility hidden for the table  <div [ngStyle]="{'visibility' : !isloading ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"> instead of doing it as < div *ngIf> it works.. don know what is the case